# ¿Como puedo llegar desde un ELB de AWS a una instancia RDS?

Tags: aws

Buen día Colegas.
Intentaré ir al punto rápidamente.

Tengo dos instancias EC2 (A y B), con codeigniter 2, que pasan por un balanceador de carga. Ambas consumen un RDS (BD MySQL, con varías BDs), que trae información para distintos módulos, consultando varias BDs. Existen algunos módulos de codeigniter que **no pueden llegar a RDS a través del balanceador**. Todas las configuraciones hacía las BDs apuntan a la IP del RDS y se conectan sin problemas. De hecho si cargo el módulo (con dificultades) directamente en el navegador (sin pasar por el balanceador) puedo llegar a RDS sin problemas (se cargan los datos bien). Pero por el balanceador me sale el error '*502 bad gateway*'.

Investigué por problemas de codeigniter y no existen errores de lógica. De otra manera, no se cargarían los datos al cargar el módulo directamente (sin pasar por el balanceador). Desconozco que puede estar sucediendo.

Agradezco de antemano, vuestras opiniones.

Comment: Yo no iría hacia la BD a través del balanceador. La BD para todos los efectos está en la DMZ de tu despliegue y cada nodo debería llegar a la BD directamente. ¿No? El balanceador está para que las peticiones públicas lleguen a tu solución y usen alguno de los EC2 con codeigniter y nada más. Si necesitas redundancia en la capa de persistencia, debes usar Multi-AZ o alguna otra característica en RDS; el balanceador no es pa eso :)

Comment: Alfabravo, haré el alcance (observación) al equipo de arquitectura. Agradecido!!
Aunque, según entiendo las instancias SI llegan directamente al RDS. El tema es que cuando me conecto al portal y paso por el balanceador, la conexión hacia la RDS falla arrojando el error 502.

Comment: Sin logs es sólo una historia ;) Con logs y detalles de la configuración, puede ser una pregunta que podamos responder. Llegar a la app por un balanceador no debería cambair nada en la configuración de BD, así que... te queda la carga de la prueba

Comment: Estimados, descubrí (buscando los logs) que si existe conexión entre las instancias y el RDS. Pero al momento de mostrar el resultset en el portal arroja un 502. No veo errores en el PHP, no veo errores en la instancia. La cuestión cambió.

Comment: El error HTTP 502 es un bad gateway, que lo puede dar el balanceador o cualquier otro equipo intermedio. Investiga y reformula la pregunta si deseas.